# Empty values in pandas -- most memory-efficient way to filter out empty values for some columns but keep empty values for one column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, filter, nan

Using Python, I have a large file (millions of rows) that I am reading in with Pandas using pd.read_csv. My goal is to minimize the amount of memory I use as much as possible.

Out of about 15 columns in the file, I only want to keep 6 columns. Of those 6 columns, I have different needs for the empty rows.

Specifically, for 5 of the columns, I'd like to filter out / ignore all of the empty rows. But for 1 of the columns, I need to keep only the empty rows.

What is the most memory-efficient way to do this?

I guess I have two problems:

First, looking at [the documentation for Pandas read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), it's not clear to me if there is a way to filter out empty rows. Are there a set of parameters and specifications for read_csv -- or with some other method --that I can use to filter out empty rows?

Second, is it possible to filter out empty rows only for some columns but then keep all of the empty rows for one of my columns?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you use [`dask.dataframe`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html). Syntax is pandas-like, but it deals with chunking and optimal memory management. Only when you need the result in memory should you translate the dataframe back to `pandas`, where of course you will need sufficient memory to hold the result in a dataframe.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = dd.read_csv('file.csv')

# filtering and manipulation logic
df = df.loc[....., ....]

# compute & return to pandas
df_pandas = df.compute()
```